# Building QGIS on windows 7 error

Tags: build, qgis

I followed the instructions [here](https://htmlpreview.github.io/?https://raw.github.com/qgis/QGIS/master/doc/INSTALL.html#toc13) to build the latest Qgis source code on windows 7 x64, but when i build the solution for the first time i encounter this error:

> cannot open source file "qgsversion.h"    qgis_core
>
> identifier "QGSVERSION" is undefined  qgis_core

in the source file `qgis.cpp` at the lines:

```
#ifndef QGSVERSION
#include "qgsversion.h"
#endif
```

and:

```
const char *Qgis::QGIS_DEV_VERSION = QGSVERSION;
```

The problem is the file `qgsversion.h` is not exists in the source code which i cloned it from the github.
I think it must be created after executing the CMake build file but not created.

Regards.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have the same problem, I solved this by building the "version" project first. It will give an error indicating the problem.

As a workaround I created the qgsversion.h file in the build directory myself. There is only one row inside the file with **#define QGSVERSION "3b7d2e3360"**

This row and the correct version number is shown in the output window of visual studio when you try to build the "version" project (when rebuilding fails).

I hope this helps, by making qgsversion.h, I was able to build qgis_core.dll